# Hybrid Mobile Application (C# & Bootstrap)

Tags: c#, google-play, internet-connection

I developed a Hybrid Mobile Application using `C#` and `Bootstrap`, I published it on Google Play and it is working fine, but when the user tries to open the application when there is no internet connection, a message appears "Webpage not available" The webpage at HTTP://... might be temporarily down or ...

The question is: how to avoid this message or how to customize it with my message or my `web form`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code. First Check internet connection using WebClient & then return custom page if connection is not available.

```
public void MyMethod()
        {
            if (CheckInternetConnection() == false)
            {
                Response.Redirect("custompage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //your application method
            }
        }

        public bool CheckInternetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var obj = new WebClient())
                {
                    using (var stream = obj.OpenRead("http://www.google.co.in"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but where to put this code, shall I put it in Default.aspx or somewhere else?